# State monads: trading one pattern for another?

Tags: haskell, abstraction, monads, boilerplate, state-monad

So I'm writing a game in Haskell, and I'm expressing a player's turn as a series of state-altering functions that correlate to various turn phases. Originally, this looks something like:

```
let game'  = phase1 game
    game'' = phase2 game'
-- etc.
```

Prime candidate for State monadosity, right? This leads to the more elegant:

```
do
  phase1
  phase2
-- etc.
```

However, then it seems like I have to change `phase1`, `phase2`, et al to begin with a boilerplate "State getting" step:

```
phase1 = get >>= \game -> -- ...
```

I'm hoping there's a way to abstract this out, so I can avoid boilerplate on both the caller and the callee. I'm just too new to know what this way is (this is my first real Haskell project). Any advice?

Comment: `... . phase3 . phase2 . phase1 $ game`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it's not quite monadosic yet.  This is a prime candidate for an [Endo](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.2/html/libraries/base/Data-Monoid.html#t%3AEndo) monoid.  This leads to the more elegant

```
game = mconcat [ phase1, phase2, ... ]
```

And each phase is written:

```
phase1 = Endo $ \game -> ...
```

You would move to a monad if you needed to return a some additional data along with the new state in each phase.  In that case a simple function will make your boilerplate more tolerable:

```
phase :: (GameState -> GameMonad a) -> GameMonad a
phase f = f =<< get
```

And then a phase is written:

```
phase1 = phase $ \game -> do ...
```

But if you want to use the state, you are probably going to have to give it a name (unless you can finagle pointfreeness by, say, using [gets](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/libraries/mtl/Control-Monad-State.html#v%3Agets) or [data-accessor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-accessor)), and in that case you can't get much terser than a function and a lambda.

Comment: Or `game = mconcat $ map Endo [phase1, phase2, ...]` and `phase1 game = ...`

Comment: `appEndo . mconcat . map Endo = foldr (.) id`   I am proposing the use of `Endo` more as an abstraction, rather than just a technique to compose a list of functions.  I don't know what I mean by that though :-P